# Already defined delegate

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates

I heard once that .net introduced an already defined delegate with no parameter that we could use instead of creating one.

I'm having a hard time finding it and for what version of .net. (if it really exists)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`System.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx). If you are not using .NET Framework 3.5 (where `Action` was introduced), you can perhaps instead use [`System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) which has the same signature.